# Converting a Model to a JSON object in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

How do I convert a `Model` to a JSON object in ASP.NET Core MVC?

I used to use the `Json.Encode()` method in MVC 5, but I cannot get this to compile in ASP.NET Core MVC. What is the replacement?

Answer (score 1):

Upto MVC 5, `Json.Encode()` works. But in MVC Core, we don't have `Encode()` method. Instead of it, we have `Serialize()` method. You can convert `Model`/`ViewBag` to json object as follows,

```
var x = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
```